# swapping 2 items in an array, but not passing it by reference

Tags: c++, arrays

```
void swap(int a[], int size){
   ...............
}

int main(){
   int x[4] = {4,5,3,12} ;
   swap(x,4) ;
   // print array here - some elements are swapped
}
```

So I'm not sure how it is possible for the swap-function to change the order of elements
since it is **passed by value** in `void swap`?

If I do something like this: `void swap( int (&a)[], int size)`
then the original array in my main function would get changed, but how does swap function swap elements, if it just **copies the array**, and hence should not make any effect on the array in main?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't put tag information in your subject line - that's what tags are for (providing topic type and language so they can be grouped together for searching and display). Thanks. :)

Comment: I don't understand, do you not want it to change the original? If not, why have a swap function? Also, passing an array to a function should be passing the pointer to the array, so, it shouldn't be passing by value anyways.

Comment: It's not passed by value, an argument of `int a[]` decays into an `int*` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and C++, when you pass an array to a function, you are actually only passing its address (yes, by value, but of course that doesn't change anything since an address passed by value or not always points to the same location).

In the function, whatever element of the array you access or change would be the original one.

So basically, your answer is that you got everything right and no need to do anything.

Example:

```
void swap(int a[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; ++i)
    {
        a[i] ^= a[size-1-i];   // If you are interested
        a[size-1-i] ^= a[i];   // try to understand
        a[i] ^= a[size-1-i];   // how this works
    }
}

int main(){
   int x[4] = {4,5,3,12} ;
   swap(x,4) ;
   // print array here - some elements are swapped
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are not copied when passed as a function arguments. They are "decayed" (automatically converted) to pointers to appropriate first elements. So this code

```
void swap(int a[], int size) { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
void swap(int* a, int size) { ... }
```

which should now explain the behavior observed.

(And if indeed you want to prevent that conversion, pass the array by reference).

Answer (score 2):

The array is not passed by value, it decays into an int*. Check this code:

```
void swap(int a[], int size){
}

void swap(int* a, int size){
}

int main()
{
}
```

Now see what the compiler says:

```
$ g++ -Wall test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘void swap(int*, int)’:
test.cpp:4:6: error: redefinition of ‘void swap(int*, int)’
test.cpp:1:6: error: ‘void swap(int*, int)’ previously defined here
```

Answer (score 1):

It works because you are not passing the array by value. Passing an array to a function is the same as passing a pointer to the first element in the array. Thus, you are not actually passing by value.

For this reason, I recommend using the more obvious notation:

```
void swap(int* a, int size)
```

You would use the double pointer:

```
void swap(int** a, int size)
```

or

```
void swap(int & a[], int size)
```

only if you want the function to change the memory address of the original array.
i.e. You reallocate the memory and want the caller to receive the new array. Of course, in this case you would probably cause a nasty leak.

If you want to enforce call by value behavior then make the argument const.

```
void swap(const int* a, int size)
```

This will prevent the method from being allowed to alter the array in any way. This is useful when you are passing a video buffer or something to a user but you do not want them to corrupt the data.